# assigning object when Including a HTML-fragment?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the following html-fragment that fills a div with simple data: (`"list.html"`)

```
<div class="eventBox" ng-repeat="element in elements">
   <h1>{{element.title}}</h1>
   <span>{{element.description}}</span>    
</div>
```

Now I want to include this fragment into different html-documents. Each of them have different lists which share the same structure.

For example a part of the controller:

```
$scope.persons={       
   elements:[
      { title:'John Doe', description:'this is John!'},
      { title:'Jane Doe', description:'The wife of John'}
   ]
}
$scope.buildings={
   elements:[
      { title:'Millerntor', description:'soccer stadium'},
      { title:'Jungfernstieg', description:'exit here for alster boat trips'}´
    ]
}
```

So what I want to achieve is something like that:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
   <span>Users:</span>
   <div ng-include="list.html" ng-useproperty="{{persons}}
   <span>Buildings:</span>
   <div ng-include="list.html" ng-useproperty="{{buildings}}
</div>
```

Of course there is no "ng-useproperty" in AngularJS. But is there another way to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the perfect use-case for an [angular directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) ...

```
var myListDirective = function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: "list.html",
    scope: {
      "elements": "="
    }
  };
};
```

Your angular module would look something like:

```
var app = angular.module('MainApp', [])
    .directive('listDirective', myListDirective);
```

And then the html looks like:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
   <span>Users:</span>
   <div list-directive elements="persons"></div>
   <span>Buildings:</span>
   <div list-directive elements="buildings></div>
</div>
```